# Remove function is randomizing the values of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I've write a simple linked list in C, the problem occures when I try to remove the first node of the list, only the first node every other node can be remove without any problems. Here is my code:

```
struct LinkedList * search_ret_prev_node(struct LinkedList *lst, int data){
//function that return the node before the one that contains the value of "data"
}
    void remove_node(struct LinkedList *lst, int data){
        if(lst->data == data){
            if(lst->next == NULL){  free(lst);  }
            else{
                 struct LinkedList *temp = lst;
                 lst = temp->next;
                 free(temp);
            }
        return;
    }
    else{
        struct LinkedList *prev_node = search_ret_prev_node(lst, data);
        if(prev_node == NULL){return;}
        if(prev_node->next->next == NULL){
            free(prev_node->next); 
            prev_node->next = NULL;
        }
        еlse{
             struct LinkedList *temp= prev_node->next;
             prev_node->next = temp->next;
             free(temp);
       }
    }
}

int main(){
   struct LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
   list->data = 4;
   list->next = NULL
 // adding a few nodes, let's say that the first one contains the number 7
   remove(list, 7);
}
```

Now as I said the problem is that after I call the remove function on the first node, it randomize the list, I get values similar to 21415135 which aren't suppose to be in the list, probably I'm accessing memory to another program. I've removed some details, because the function is working perfectly, if I try to remove any other node different than the first one. Any ideas why this's happening?

Comment: The problem is if you free the first node, the list pointer in main becomes invalid, because you removed it!  You need to either return list from the remove routine or have a first entry that is permanent and can't be removed.

Comment: your function name is `remove_node` not just `remove` (you use in main function to call)

Comment: Is it single-linked list? Who points to head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell there's the problem as soon as you see this:

```
remove(list, 7);
//     ^
```

See something suspicious? Exactly, there's no ampersand! It means that no matter what `remove` does, the value of `list` pointer is not going to change, because the pointer is passed by value. Hence, removing the first item is not going to change the list in a correct way: what you would end up with is a *dangling pointer*.

There are two common ways of addressing this:

- Make a "fake" first node that is always ignored, or
- Pass a pointer to a pointer to your `remove` function.

I prefer the second approach:

```
void remove(struct LinkedList **lstPtr) {
    ... // Add an extra level of dereference
}
...
remove(&list, 7);
```

Comment: @Jiminion The only problem with returning a pointer that I see is that it's too easy to omit the assignment, especially for programmers new to your library. It is a problem because the compiler is not going to catch it, and there would be no immediate consequences in most cases, i.e. unless the initial element of the list is removed.

Comment: Now, i prefer the second method too(passing a pointer to pointer)

Comment: I suppose it is a matter of style. I prefer to avoid a double pointer if there is an easy alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Remove_node should return the (possibly updated) list value so that the list entries in the scope that it was called from will remain valid.